# Photoswipe - No Gallery View - No Nav Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, photoswipe

I have built this based on the online tutorials and Photoswipe documentation.
http://sfrunningtours.com/photoswipetest.html

It previews equal across all browsers (Safari, FF, Chrome). But there are 2 issues.

First, pix are stacked and not inserted into a gallery view like the brochure

Second issue is there are no nav buttons. Otherwise photos swipe fine.

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

<link href="css/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
        (function(window, PhotoSwipe){
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                var
                    options = {},
                    instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options );
            }, false);
        }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="Home">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>PhotoSwipe Test</h1>
    </div>

<div data-role="content" >      
    <ul id="Gallery" style="list-style:none">
        <li><a href="images/full/01.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/01.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/full/02.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/02.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/full/03.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/03.jpg" alt="Image 03" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/full/04.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/04.jpg" alt="Image 04" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/full/05.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/05.jpg" alt="Image 05" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/full/06.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/06.jpg" alt="Image 06" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using the jquery version but no joy there either. Have also added / substituted different css I've found in both several versions and online tutorials. Nothing. JS and CSS files were downloaded from the Photoswipe site and have been put on my server in directory js and css under main. I have verified they are being called.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but explains how the JavaScript works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212087/understanding-obscure-javascript-code

Comment: Usefulcat. That was in fact *useful* thanks :) Ultimately I abandoned Photoswipe for a lighter, cleaner slider. Thanks for the pointers though, they help!

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems displaying the gallery when making modifications to the script. Try it without your edits.

Photo Swipe is set up to display thumbnails of your images. When you tap on an image, it should open the gallery view. Make sure your divs have the correct class attributes as in the sample html if you use the sample CSS. For example:

```
<div id="Gallery">
    <div class="gallery-list">
        <div class="gallery-item"><a href="[your image file]/></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><a href="[your image file]/></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"><a href="[your image file]/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of using list